# Hive "show tables" analogue for "ls -l"

Tags: hive

Is there a way to tell `hive` command `show tables` that I want to see the "long" output, including whatever is printed by `show tblproperties` for each table (similar to `ls -l` shell command)?

Comment: AFAIK `show tables` won't show you anything else, what details would you expect to see?

Comment: @Wojtek: `tblproperties`